# React Images Won't Load when I pass my src value through array

Tags: reactjs

So when I use `src={require('images/img-1')}` my image loads fine

However, I'm trying to pass in the src through a data component, so the code would look like this

```
export const CardData = [
{
src: '../images/img-2.jpg',
text: 'Travel',
},
```

Then I map through my code and would use

```
{CardData.map((item, index) => {
  <img
 src={item.src} />
```

But this doesn't work because I can't add require in it. How would I write the same code but include require?

I tried `src={require{item.src}}` but it didn't work for me

Comment: why are you putting your require in the `src={}` as opposed to the top level? curious as to if there is some advantage I don't know about (TOTALLY possible) - if not, then i would say you shouldn't be doing that, personally it seems like it would ultimately possibly effect performance. Other than that - have you tried using the exact same path that is working for you with the require? `images/img-2` instead of adding the `../` ? if that doesn't work then evvaluate how your static files are delivered, or check the file structure you are referring to in your code

Comment: the images load fine when I do require(../images/img-1) but whenever I transfer the image src to a data file and pass it through an array, I don't know how to implement the require correctly. How would i add it to the top level?

Comment: is the path you are passing correct to the _component calling that data_?

Comment: yes everything else works for my other properties such as text, description, etc. but the only thing not working in the image. It wasn't loading before I made the array either, so it has nothing to do with my array code, it never loaded from the start of my project until I added require()

Comment: i think ultimately, you have to look at how the static files/images are being served - most likely in your server,js file if you have one. if that's set up right, then you should be able to serve images from anywhere in the app with `images/img` (assuming you set it up like that) and it won't matter what the file structure of the components is. overall, you haven't provided the code needed to debug this... pls provide your file structure and any code that deals with delivering assets ;)

Comment: so I put my images into my public folder and it looks like it's working now, but it doesn't make any sense because I changed the src on my array from '../' to just '/images' and both times I refresh it loads up?

Comment: yes, it makes sense - somewhere in your code you have a setup that looks inside the public folder for static assets - so the `../` is throwing that off and telling it to look one directory _up_ from the current file - which is probably not where the image is actually stored :) \

Comment: so does it matter if I store my images in public or src folder?

Comment: yes - does this app have a server? i want to _try_ to help you identify where this is happening

Comment: idk I just did create-react-app and currently building my front end out

Comment: do  a  `find all` in your code and look for something that looks like )but may not exactly be like) `server.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../../static')` in your case, it may say `public` instead of `static` --- you may need to just do the `find all` on `path.resolve` to narrow it down. but what _that line is doing_ is telling the app: `serve static files from ./static without needing /static in pathname`  - again, yours may say `public` not `static` idk

Comment: i typed server and on package-lock and yarn.lock show results, but I couldn't find anything about static. Public also isn't showing

Comment: server,js is a file - and you wouldn't' find what your looking from in a package.js or lockfile - those have to do with dependancies mostely (and some scripts but this wouldn't live there most likely, it would be in the server,js file assuming you have a server) it would be useful for your understanding to be able to see how static files are being served from your public directory - but i don't have your codebase in front of me to help you find it. But in short, yes. Put your images in your public directory if you want to use `images/some-image`

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should map your array like this

```
{ CardData.map((item, index) =>
  <img
     src={item.src} 
  />
}
```

Then you don't need to require the image in the tag and you just need to import it at the top
like this

```
import MyImg from '../images/img-2.jpg';

// use MyImg allias for using that image
export const CardData = [
{
  src: MyImg,
  text: 'Travel',
},
```